# will google bots and crawlers recognize data stored in localstorage and sessionstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, bots, google-crawlers

I have implemented localstorage and sessionstorage on my website to store data on browser.

I doubt that whether google bots and crawlers will recognizes the local storage data and crawl it ?

The process is like once local storage data is set i am setting cookie. then based on cookie existence, i will pull data from local storage.

will this be ok or how to optimize for seo purpose.

And will local storage will improve any page load time..or rendering time..

Comment: You've got server different questions here. Most of the answers will be some combination of "The fine details of search engine indexers are secret so we don't know", "Depends on how you are using it", and "Compared to what?". Write [good JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and you probably don't need to worry about support.

Comment: If still interested please review http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71852/do-web-crawlers-have-local-storage/85325#85325